# compatibility issue with Skype (2.2 beta) and centos6 (64bit)

Tags: skype, centos, compatibility

I'm facing some difficulties in installing skype with centos6 (64bit), Every time I tried, after system reboot centos stuck in the loading screen.

But without installing skype my Centos6 (64bit) works fine.

Just wanted to know is there any known compatibility issue with Skype (2.2 beta) and centos6 (64bit)

When I googled, I couldn't find such issue directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Skype 2.2 is known to cause freezes on CentOS installs, but usually on pre-6 versions. A common "fix" is to uninstall the RPM (rpm -e [package name]) and then re-install. Make sure there is a `~/.Skype/Logs` directory too.

Sadly, and frustratingly, a solid reason for the problem does not yet seem to be known and many people are left uninstalling and reinstalling Skype. Then again, that's why they call it `beta`